# Escape system of SLS vs Ares I

Tags: sls, launch-escape-system, constellation-program

One of the criticism directed at the Ares I rocket was [the danger during a launch termination of the solid-propellant 1st stage](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewsr.html?pid=31792). As far as I understood it, a terminated Titan IV solid-propellant rocket filled the air in the area with a "rain" of hot debris and the USAF 45th Space Wing assumed that the Ares I launch escape system would not get the capsule out of the dangerous area before the parachutes would deploy (and get destroyed).

The SLS is still using solid-propellant boosters. Are the concerns for the Ares I still relevant? (Or has it been shown that they were never relevant for the Ares I in the first place?) Has the launch escape system been upgraded since then? Or is the flight path for the SLS different enough that debris from a blown-up rocket motor would not be in the same area as the escaped capsule anymore?